# Find the path in matrix using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have list of aplhabets and i compare them using numpy
like in file 1 i have

```
File 1

a,b,c

c,d,f

File 2

c,d,f
```

I compare every element of file1 with file 2 and generate matrix like

```
0 0 0 (a compares with all of aplhabets in file b)

0 0 0(bcompares with all of aplhabets in file b)

0 0 1(c compares with all of aplhabets in file b)


1 0 0(c compares with all of aplhabets in file b)

0 1 0(d compares with all of aplhabets in file b)

0 0 1(f compares with all of aplhabets in file b)
```

Now i have to show that there is a path from a to d how can i find the path?

Comment: what do you mean by "a compares with all of aplhabets in file b" ? Can you be a bit more clear on how you generated the matrix? May be post the code snippet. Also what you mean by  a path ?

Comment: i have strings which i am going to compare if both of them are equl then i print 1 else print 0. Example mentioned above completely describes it

Comment: a,b,c and c,d,f have have a path a,b,c,d because c is common in both of strings

Comment: You understand the question?

Comment: I have to tell the common elements between files

Comment: So you mean in the above example you want the output to be c d f ? Common elements between the two files ?

Comment: I want to relate the two strings with common elements between them kindly help me i m stuck

Comment: I want to help but I still don't the question. What do you mean relate ? how  can two strings be related? You need to give a clear example. 

s1 = "abc"
s2= "dcf"
s3="xyz"

now are you saying s1 & s2 are related because they have 'c' as common ? Where as s1 and s3 are not ?